# generate dynamic unique random registration Id in java

Tags: java

I am assigned a task to generate dynamic unique random registration Id and store in a file and when a  gain it is generated  it should read the file and give a  new Id.
Thanks in advance...

**The code i tried is below....**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("Input.txt");        

        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            int randomInteger = random.nextInt();
            filewriter.write(randomInteger);
            System.out.println("\n Random Integer in Java: " + randomInteger);
        }

        filewriter.flush();
        filewriter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to continue with this approach, you are going to need to scan the entire file each time you generate a new potential ID to make sure it is not a duplicate.  If you take the database approach, you can simply assign counting numbers in order, and read the last line of the file each time to see what the latest number is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your solution, as stated by Tim Biegeleisen, when you generate a new random Integer you must read your file and check if that Integer has already been generated. If it has then you must generate a new one.

There are some issues with this solution however. If you are going to generate a large amount of ID's from this code the runtime will continuely increase as you will need to search the file every time you generate a new ID. If you don't mind sacrificing some randomness I would suggest only saving a prefix for the last id generated and ensuring that prefix is incremented after each generation. This allows only a short read for each generation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UUID like `UUID.randomUUID()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

or use AtomicInteger and call `incrementAndGet()` each time you need a new value.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html